# lcms error using ImageMagick compare on JPEGs with colour profile

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, photoshop, ghostscript

### When running `compare`

```
compare -metric MSE some-image-1.jpg some-image-2.jpg /dev/null
```

#### 1) When images are identical (OK)

```
0 (0)
```

This is what I would expect to see.

#### 2) When images differ (OK)

```
Error: Command failed: 13.1266 (0.000200299)
```

I can get the data that I want, but I'm not sure why it's presented as an error.

#### 3) When image is a JPEG with a Photoshop colour profile (ISSUE)

```
Error: Command failed: lcms: Error #12288; Corrupted memory profile
```

This is the real issue, and only happens on JPEG images with a Photoshop colour profile - can anyone point me to why this would happen?

### Environment

OS X 10.9.4

GhostScript 9.07 at `/opt/Ghostscript`

compare at `/opt/ImageMagick/bin/compare`

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.8-6 Q16 x86_64 2014-02-17 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC
Delegates: bzlib fftw jng jpeg lcms lzma png tiff webp xml zlib
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not clear why you think this is Ghostscript related, ImageMagick processes JPEG files without using Ghostscript, as far as I'm aware. I'd have to guess that the version of lcms being used has a bug, or limitation. In fact, I think it would be better to be using lcms2 instead of lcms. As I recall the developer isn't working on lcms any more, and hasn't been for some time, its all lcms2 now.

Comment: Thanks KenS, I just mentioned that Ghostscript is installed for completeness, incase it could be related. Is it possible to swap the ImageMagick delegate from lcms to lcms2?

Comment: I'm sorry I really haven't a clue there. I would guess not, that the library is built in, but I could very easily be wrong.